# How can I simultaneously use Latex and Markdown syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2 or TextMate 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, textmate2

I use Pandoc which allows mixing of markdown and latex. It would be nice to have syntax highlighting working for both. Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Consolidate the `*.tmLanguage` files for both Markdown and LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a new language grammar for Pandoc files that incorporates the Markdown and LaTeX grammars. There are two ways to include rules from other grammars:

1. Use an include rule and reference elements from the other grammars. For example this would reference include the complete LaTeX and Markdown grammars:

   ```
   { patterns = ( 
     { include = 'text.html.markdown'; },
     { include = 'text.tex.latex'; },
     ); 
   }
   ```

   It is also possible to cherry pick rules from the grammars repository by using this form:

   ```
   { include = 'text.html.markdown#block'; }
   ```
2. Use injection grammars. You can read more about those on [the TextMate blog](http://blog.macromates.com/2012/injection-grammars-project-variables/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies for the delay, however it's not clear to me where this snippet should sit... It looks like Json which might be converted to a plist, but isn't valid json. Guidance for ST2 would be most helpful.

Comment: OK, so I found this page on syntax definitions in ST2 using yaml: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/sublime-text-2/reference/syntaxdefs.html    and I've tried this: https://gist.github.com/puterleat/7907963  to no avail... nothing gets highlighted when that definition is activated.

Comment: I'm not sure about Sublime (I don't use it), but in Textmate 2 you can choose Bundles -> Edit Bundles from the menu. Either create a new language grammar in an existing bundle or create a new bundle. Check out the documentation on how to write grammars: http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars